# Trigger created with warning

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

As sysdate cannot be used in check constraint, tried to a trigger to fulfill the purpose.
But its showing " Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors."

I am posting my syntax below. I am using Oracle 10g database.

```
create table birth 
(name varchar2(30), DOB date);

insert into birth  values ('Ravi', sysdate+1 );
```

1 row inserted.
Now technically this is wrong. To prevent this I an creating a trigger

```
create or replace trigger birth_trigger
before insert or update of dob on birth
for each row
begin 
if (dob >=sysdate)
then 
raise_application_error (-20501, 'DOB cannot be greater than sysdate');
end if;
end;
```

Now here I am getting the "Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors."
Not been able to resolve the problem.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you are attempting to reference the "dob" column incorrectly.  If you execute, "show errors" , you should see the message, "[Error] PLS-00201 (7: 8): PLS-00201: identifier 'DOB' must be declared".  You need to preface the column with the :new prefix (default) to access the record's values.

```
create or replace trigger birth_trigger
before insert or update of dob on birth
for each row
begin 
   if ( :new.dob >=sysdate)
  then 
     raise_application_error (-20501, 'DOB cannot be greater than sysdate');
   end if;
end;
```

I would recommend using an IDE to do PL/SQL development, such as Oracle free SQLDeveloper. Also, read the [Oracle Documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm) on triggers.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
create or replace trigger birth_trigger
before insert or update of dob on birth
referencing old as old new as new
for each row
begin 
    if (
        trunc ( to_date(:new.dob, 'DD/MM/YYYY' )) >= trunc (to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY' ))
        ) 
    then 
        raise_application_error (-20501, 'DOB cannot be greater than sysdate');
    end if;
end;
```

in code i have used new and old keywords for accessing the new values inserted in the birth table.

Comment: instead of the above condition use this condition(:new.dob>=sysdate)